# Accessing Variables in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to access variables from Pipeline > Library like this
`$(AndroidKeyAlias)` but I can't see any output. I have tried a couple of other ways as well.
[image: Azure Pipeline > Library]

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
      trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - azure-develop
variables:
  - group: Example Mobile App
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

stages:
  - stage: initialise_environment
    displayName: Initialise Environment
    jobs:
      - template: steps/azure-initialise-pipeline.yml
```

**azure-initialise-pipeline.yml**

```
jobs:
  - job: initialise_node
    displayName: initialise node 
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true
    - bash: |
        FOO="some value"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FOO]$AndroidKeyAlias"
    - bash: |
       set -ex
       mkdir -p packages
       echo $AndroidKeyAlias > packages.json
       cat packages.json
      env:
        CACHIX_AUTH_TOKEN: $(AndroidKeyAlias)
    - bash: |
        echo "$(FOO)"
```

As you can see I have tried getting variables values but I am not getting any output.

How do I get this value? I have tied fetching the values using the Azure CLI tool and I am getting following output

```
authorized: true
description: ''
id: 123
name: Example Mobile App
providerData: null
type: Vsts
variables:
  AndroidKeyAlias:
    isSecret: true
    value: null
  AndroidKeyAliasPassword:
    isSecret: true
    value: null
  AndroidKeyStorePassword:
    isSecret: true
    value: null
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're completely messing up the notation for bash environment variable substitution and the Azure Pirelines variable substitution. On top of that there are rules for when variables are available to a template and when not and also specific notation that might be needed there...

In general, when you want Azure pipelines to inline the value of a variable for you, use:

```
$(VariableName)
```

These variables will be substituted at the time that the task is invoked and will hold whatever value the variable has at that step in the job

Alternatively, use

```
${{ variables.Variablename }}
```

For 'compiletime' substitution. These will be expanded before the job even starts to run and will use the value that is available during template expansion and workflow initialisation.

If you are inside a bash script you can use any of the above mentioned syntaxis. You can also use an environment variable to pass the contents in

```
- bash: | 
    $VAR
  env:
    VAR: $(Variablename)
- pwsh: |
    $env:VAR
  env:
    VAR: $(Variablename)
```

By passing in variables through the environment you don't have to mix the different variable substitution notations. It makes it easier to see what's going on.

When setting an environment variable in a bash step, the value won't be available in a subsequent step. The environment is cleaned up between steps for security and reasons.

For this reason, this won't work:

```
# Doesn't work
- bash: |
    FOO="some value"
- bash: |
    echo $FOO
```

There are special strings you can stream to the log that will instruct the agent to set a variable for the subsequent steps in the same job.

With templates things can become even harder, as you can also pass variables to a template where it's being called. You can do this with template parameters. The advantage of this syntax is that's it's very evident when you're passing in data:

```
jobs:
- template: templates/npm-with-params.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    name: Linux
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

With a template defined as:

```
parameters:
- name: name  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  default: ''
- name: vmImage
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
```

See:

- [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates)
- [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)
- [stetting variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)